# Salary cut-off date

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, employment

I started a new job on 6 Dec. The employment contract says:

"payable monthly in arrears, in equal instalments by direct bank transfer on or around the
last day of each month, minus any statutory and/or voluntary deductions"

I was not paid on 31 Dec as I was expecting, and when I inquired with the admin person they told me

"Our salary cut off date (the date by which we have to finalise the salary payments each month) is the first Friday of each month. Since the first Friday was 3 Dec, your first salary payment date will be 31 Jan 2022"

This seems unreasonable to me. At the very least I would have expected them to have informed me about this soon after I joined, if not prior to joining - particularly with it being December/Christmas. I had the chance to join on 29 Nov, but decided to have a week off. Had I know about this salary cut off date I would not have waited.

Since the cut-off date is not mentioned in the contract, do I have any legal grounds to request payment as soon as possible ? I assume not, but just want to check.

Comment: Employment law isn't my forte, but there's certainly no legal grounds _preventing_ you from requesting an interim payment. Such an early cut-off date in the month for salaries is very odd in my experience, and something like that should have been made clear to you from the outset - while possibly not legally required, it's certainly something that a business would want to make clear to new hires since it's not good practice to intentionally aggravate employees during their first month. And messing with your income is guaranteed to aggravate anyone.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins thank you - that's pretty much what I was thinking / hoping for !